# How to get the following $\pi$ an isomorphism?

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory

Let $A$ be a finite dimensional algebra over a field k. $D=Hom_k(-,k)$ is the dualiy. $V:=Hom_A(D(A),A)$.

In a paper, it says the map $\pi: Hom_A(D(A),Hom_{A^{op}}(V,A)) \rightarrow Hom_{A^{op}}(V,Hom_A(D(A),A))$ which sends $f \in Hom_A(D(A),Hom_{A^{op}}(V,A))$ to $\pi(f) \in Hom_{A^{op}} (V,Hom_A(D(A),A))$ such that $\pi(f)(v)(\delta)=f(\delta)(v)$ for any $\delta \in D(A)$ and $v \in V$ is an isomorphism. It's easy to get $\pi$ is injective. But how to get $\pi$ is an isomorphism?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a consequence of the general adjunction between $\text{Hom}$ and $\otimes$ for bimodules:

> **Fact:** Let $A,B$ be rings, $_AM$ a left $A$-module, $N_B$ a right $B$-module and $_AP_B$ an $A$-$B$-bimodule. Then there are canonical and natural isomorphisms of abelian groups: $$\text{Hom}_A(_AM,\text{Hom}_B(N_B,{_AP_B}))\cong\text{Hom}_{A\text{-}B}(_AM\otimes_{\mathbb Z} N_B\ , {_AP_B})\cong\text{Hom}_B(N_B, \text{Hom}_A(_AM,{{_AP}_B})).$$

The formulas are the apparent ones; e.g., going from left to right or vice versa is given by a 'swapping' formula as you have already written down in your question.